# Reinstalling windows 10 free upgrade, which key should i use

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, product-key, license-key

Hello my parents updated their laptop with Windows 7 to Windows 10, apparently by mistake. Since they do it themselves, I did not see the terms of conditions nor any information displayed before the upgrade. Since then they get used to the new appearance of windows so I did not do the rollback to windows 7 for them.

Now I start wondering if in the future I will do the disk format and fresh install of windows (which I usually do for them every 3 - 4 years), **how will I be able to activate their copy of Windows 10 after fresh installation?** Will I be able to use their Win7 key?

Please note that my parents **do not have the hotmail account**, and I don't want to force them to make one.

Comment: You don't have to use a key, and you only have one key anyways, the Windows 7 key.  How this all works by the way is well documented

Comment: @Ramhound The initial upgrade doesn't require a key as it finds it on your pc, but a fresh install would require a key as wiping the machine would also wipe the previous key.

Comment: @RyanIG You are 100% incorrect.  Windows 10 will automatically upgrade because of its hardware based digital entitlement license.  Go read just a fraction of my Windows 10 answers, all backed up, by Microsoft links on this subject

Comment: I went through @Ramhound's history to find the answer he is talking about. I think this answer is the one he is referencing (I could be wrong though) http://superuser.com/questions/1010615/get-windows-10-activation-key-without-3rd-party-software/1010626#1010626

Comment: @Ramhound Have removed my answer, had not seen anything regarding Digital entitlement and windows 10 before interesting read though will need to look into it more, i was going off what i have read on forums

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. You can reinstall the same edition of Windows 10 that your device has a digital entitlement for without entering a product key. Read more at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10 (Don't forget to read the section with related linsk below.

Comment: @Burgi - There are so many answers, I could be talking, I don't even know if thats the one I am talking about.  I took a long time to wad through all the information on Windows 10 awhile ago, trust me a good amount of the information, was either incomplete or not accurate.

Comment: [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus) is the only program, that I have found, that displays the actual Windows license key, if you upgrade from Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 it will also display that key. Of course that information was never required, since Win 10, automatically activates on any machine its been installed on before. If its never been installed, then the key is useful, if you want to use that key to install Windows 10. Of course with that said, your Win 8.1 license key is automatically detected, so its only required for Win 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been mentioned on this site at least a 100 times.
Windows 10 has uploaded its key to a Microsoft database, together with some hardware identification.
You re-install Windows 10 WITHOUT a key.
1st time the system connects to the internet again it will check with the Microsoft database which will return the key matching the hardware identification for this system.

This does mean that you will loose the Windows 10 license if you change to much hardware (motherboard replacement). Changing just one component (HD, CPU, video-card) should be OK.

Comment: Thank you @Tonny I saw other posts but they do not mention is this connected with the server via hotmail account. Since most users have such account it could be implicit. If it is only based on the hardware specifications, thats great. 

Changing motherboard in Windows 7 cause you licence become invalid anyway, so I presumed that it is the same story with any newer version.

Comment: No key is uploaded; what is generated isn't a Windows 10 license key.   This hardware activation has no connection to your Hotmail/Microsoft account; Please improve this answer, there are since factual inaccuracies currently

Comment: @Ramhound You are right, but I didn't want to complicate the answer too much. For all intents and purposes, to the average user the result is the same and the exact technical details aren't that important.

Comment: Except what you have said, is not, factually correct?